# V brake collects metal fragments

Tags: brakes, rims, rim-brake, brake-pads

My V brake makes grinding sounds when pulled. I've checked, and it keeps collecting metal fragments, presumably from the rim. The pads are weeks old, the rim was replaced a year ago. What can cause this? Can I solve this with anything else than replacing the rim and the pads again?

Comment: just in case anyone is interested: replacing both the rim and the pads solved the problem :)